# performance generating combinations of objects with combinations of attr

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am looking for some advice on how I can better approach a couple of functions.

I have a set of 5 objects with 6 attributes on each, the number of objects can change as well as the amount of attributes.

I need to iterate over each possible combination of attribute, on each possible combination of object. No object in the set can feature the same value within the set. and for each objects attributes there are n possible values ( where n is the set size ). Values that are applicable to attributes cannot be applicable to another attribute. ie. attributeA's value, will never be a value for attributeB.

At the moment I have the objects represented as a list of lists.
eg. 
[[obj1attr_A, obj1attrB], [obj2attr_A, obj2attr_B]] etc

the problem is that itertools.combinations returns too many redundent combinations that are not valid ( ie. values that appear more often then once ). If i use a generator to return only valid combinations it is so slow that it never effectively yields a correct combination. Is there a way to filter the results in itertools.combinations efficiently?

```
#keywords is a list of possible values for each attribute
Solver.get_unique_combinations(
       itertools.combinations(itertools.product(*keywords), 5))

def get_unique_combinations(combinations):
    for combination in combinations:
        flat = [item for sublist in combination for item in sublist]
        if len(set(flat)) < len(flat):
            continue
        yield combination
```

Ive also tried using ifilter with the same problem (below), effectively the only way I can see that I am going to be able to do this is to use something other than itertools.combinations to return sets of objects with unique values in each and somehow skip the need for a filter altogether.

```
 return itertools.ifilter(lambda x: Solver.get_unique_combinations(x),
    itertools.combinations(itertools.product(*keywords), 5))

@staticmethod
def get_unique_combinations(x):
    if len(
            set(str(x).replace('[', '')
                        .replace('[', '')
                        .replace(',', '')
                        .replace('(', '')
                        .replace(')', '')
                        .split())) == len(x) * len(x[0]):
        return True
    return False
```

**EDIT: as requested - a short compilable version:

```
import itertools


def has_unique_values(iterable, attr_count):
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    counter = 0
    for element in itertools.ifilterfalse(seen.__contains__, 
            itertools.chain(iterable)):
        seen_add(element)
        counter += 1
    return counter == attr_count

keywords = [
    ["australia", "sweden", "germany", "france", "italy"],
    ["lion", "tiger", "otter", "bird", "fish"],
    ["table", "chair", "cloth", "couch", "tv"],
    ["apple", "orange", "pear", "grape", "tomato"],
    ["onion", "carrot", "mushroom", "kale", "spinach"]]

keyword_combinations = itertools.product(*keywords)
population = len(keywords[0])
attr_count = len(keywords)

unique_count = population * attr_count

for c in itertools.ifilter(lambda x: has_unique_values(x, unique_count), 
         itertools.combinations(keyword_combinations, population)):
    print c #doesnt get to here
```

Comment: Questions seeking improvement on already working code is better suited to [code-review]. Also I didn't really follow your needs, but I would be surprised if `itertools` did not provide you with ways to achieve your goal efficiently.

Comment: But what if its so slow it it cant really be considered an adequate solution? I did look through itertools but couldnt see how i could apply it to my example

Comment: Could you write small reproduceable examples that we could bench to be able to propose a better solution?

Comment: no worries, added in an edit to the bottom.

Comment: Why are you taking the product of all the keyword lists and then finding all combinations of that?

Comment: I used the product to find all possible combinations of a single object in the set. I understand my method is flawed, thats why im asking for help :) I then used combinations to find all possible combinations of the set. What I need though is just the combinations where all values are only used once.